# Slow Boot 14.04

Tags: boot, kernel, kvm-virtualization

I updated to 4.3.0-040300 kernel to get my wifi working but now booting takes much much longer. I'm using a lenovo thinkpad yoga 460, booting from an external hardrive via usb port and I've deleted the previous kernels. I've attached a picture of the screen that comes up post GRUB menu. From googling so far, it could be a problem with my graphics card and kvm but I don't know how to resolve. Please help!

[Post GRUB boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoFvW.jpg)